# Pipeline : add another feature to text classification in Python (FeatureUnion)

Tags: python, text, scikit-learn, nlp, classification

I am attempting to implement a text classification solution using scikit learn.

I have been able to get results for simple classification of text. Now I want to add another feature (non-text) into the prediction process - to improve accuracy.

**My data-set is as follows :**

- label : the target value i.e, 'sandwich', 'greeting' or 'goodbye'
- message : the text
- number_feature : randomly assigned integer. To test FeatureUnion, I have assigned same number to each category. For example, all 'sandwich' instances are given number 2

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
import sklearn 
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion 
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC


path = 'sunny_day.xlsx'                         
sms = pd.read_excel(path,header = None, names = ['label', 'message','number_feature'])   


#convert labels to a numeric value using a map and give it new column 'label_num'
sms['label_num'] = sms.label.map({'greeting' : 0, 'Goodbye' : 1, 'Sandwich' : 2})


X = sms.message
y = sms.label_num
z = sms.number_feature

# train test split
X_train = np.array(X[0:9])
X_test = np.array(X[9:])
y_train = np.array(y[0:9])
y_test = np.array(y[9:])
z_train = np.array(z[0:9])
z_test = np.array(z[9:])


def get_z(x):
    if np.array_equal(x, np.array(X_train)):
        return np.array(z_train).reshape(-1,1)
    else:
        return np.array(z_test).reshape(-1,1)


classifier = Pipeline([
    ('features', FeatureUnion([
        ('text',Pipeline([
            ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer()),
        ])),
        ('length', Pipeline([
            ('count', FunctionTransformer(get_z, validate = False)),
        ]))
    ])),
    ('clf',OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC()))])

classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred_class = classifier.predict(X_test)
y_pred_class
```

As mentioned in various posts, I have made use of FeatureUnion to accomplish this. 
However the accuracy that I get - before applying the 'rigged' number_feature feature and even after it - is 66.67%.

Why doesn't the accuracy seem to improve when given a biased feature?

The dataset :

Label        | Message              | feature_number

```
greeting   How are you?             5
greeting   How is your day?         5
greeting   Good day                 5
greeting   How is it going today?   5
Goodbye    Have a nice day          4
Goodbye    See you later            4
Goodbye    Have a nice day          4
Goodbye    Talk to you soon         4
Sandwich   Make me a sandwich.      2
Sandwich    Can you make a sandwich 2
Sandwich   Having a sandwich today? 2
Sandwich    what’s for lunch        2
```

Comment: When splitting data it is important to keep the class balance in the training and testing sets similar to the one in the complete set. You can use sklearn's train_test_split for this http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html . Note, that X in your case should imclude both indendent varuables. You can later pass X with the appropriate column label for the two kinds of features to the FeatureUnion. X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=23, stratify=y) .